# Using if statement on associated attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, nested-forms

I am trying to construct my edit form so that when an associated image with the params status == 'Before' the image shows, but if there is no image then show a file_field so that an image can be uploaded.

Associations

```
Portfolio has_many :portfolio_images
PortfolioImage belongs_to :portfolio
```

Edit Form

```
<%= f.fields_for :portfolio_images do |i| %>

  <!-- Before Image -->
  <% if i.object.status == 'Before' %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= i.label 'Before' %><br>
      <%= image_tag(i.object.image_url(:thumb)) %><br>
      <label>
        <%= i.check_box :_destroy %>
        Remove Image
      </label>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Somehow I need to say else show file_field. So if there is no `portfolio_image.status == 'Before'` but a portfolio_id exists then show this file_field so that I can update the portfolio with an image.

Comment: As an aside to your question, I would take your conditional status=='Before' and make an a method on your object so that you are calling... <% i.before_image? %> ...and hiding from the view that nasty logic it really doesn't need to know about.

Answer (score 0):

I think you know the solution i.e.

```
<div class="form-group">      
  <% if i.object.status == 'Before' %>
      <%= i.label 'Before' %><br>
      <%= image_tag(i.object.image_url(:thumb)) %><br>
      <label>
        <%= i.check_box :_destroy %>
        Remove Image
      </label>
  <% else %>
      <%= i.file_field :file %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem i have is that the image and the file_field is showing